# ESP32 pico D4 SoC(System on Chip) Heat issue

Tags: wifi, soc

I have designed my own PICO board using PICO D4 SoC with help of the document : [ESP-PICO-D4-Datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-d4_datasheet_en.pdf). Everything works perfectly fine except heat is produced when chip is using WiFi functions.

I have tested with blink and Wifi sketch for a week and **no issues found** (without plastic case covered) . My plan is to put the same board behind wall switch and will have an plastic enclosure also. Only SoC chip gets heated no other components are impacted.

Is it safe to put behind wall switch?

Does simple heatsink on SoC would solve the problem?

Can I proceed avoiding this?
[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: A badly matched antenna circuit could cause a high VSWR and feed power back into the transmitter, which would cause heating. If that's the case, I would expect to see issues in FCC emissions testing as well.

Comment: Do you have someone else's board to compare the software on?  I suspect an issue somewhere but you provide almost no information about your design.  Is there a die pad on the chip?  What have you connected it to, and how?  What is the power consumption, and is that normal?

Comment: The D4 seems pretty poorly bypassed, not sure how that affects wireless performance..  (yes there are internal caps but.. anyhow)

Comment: I'd like to see that the back of that is mostly ground plane with the die pad stitched to it with a number of vias (yes, have to be careful for solderability but it can be done) and also stitching vias between that and the front ground pour...  The fact that I see essentially no vias in that pour at all is worrisome.  And is that odd diagonal trace from c4 really the recommended way to feed that antenna?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Have updated all info about circuit and PCB top & bottom images too..

Comment: @vicatcu Please have a look at the details I have updated

Comment: I'd sprinkle some stitching vias between the top and bottom planes but at least it does look like there's a path for heat from the pad.  Right now comparing power consumption to the same software on a standard purchased board (or at least to spec expectations) would be good.  Also just do the finger temperature comparison; if a purchased board doesn't heat the chip and your does, something is probably wrong...

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did check the standard purchased which has wroom module not soc... have read some blogs, which says running wifi continuously on Pico D4 might have heating, but they say no issues... http://iot-bits.com/inside-esp32-pico-d4-design/

Comment: https://www.tinypico.com/gettingstarted#faq11

Comment: I'd get my hot air tool and take the shield off a scarifical WROOM and do a finger temperature comparison.  And again, *measure the power consumption*.  What sort of temperature is being reached, anyway?  You might also confirm that the heat is only substantial if you actually activate the wifi, and if it depends on the actual utilization (though some types of radios burn quite a bit of power receiving, too)

Comment: I did finger temp comparison on my board not inside wroom without shield... anyways will do that... not sure how to proceed now? Confused

Comment: You proceed by measuring and reporting the a) temperature and b) power consumption.  Certainly you can measure the consumption.  If you do not have a thermometer at least say if it is "warm", "hot" "uncomfortable to stay touching" or "immediate ouch" or "damaged my finger"

Comment: @ChrisStratton Have got IR thermometer and measured temperature... PICO D4 Temp is around 55 C. Node MCU Temp is  around 50 C... But it seems hot when i touch... Is running constantly around 55 - 60 okay? Can I proceed?